# Image recognition: Bas64 code and/or hash code that uniquely identifies an image irrespective of its size, format?

Tags: hash, fingerprint, image-recognition, watson

I need a way to uniquely identify an image just the way fingerprint recognition recognizes a fingerprint.

**Use case**

1) A user has taken a screenshot of a university certificate and exported it as a PDF document and shared with an employer

2) The employer then calls the Institute to share the certificate issued as a PDF file.

3) On receipt of both the certificates an application has to compare whether the 2 documents have a unique image on it

**The problem**

We all know that images can be stored in multiple formats like JPEG, GIF, PNG, BMP etc. And when user copy pastes or scans that on a word document\pdf the grid size of the copied image may differ. Both these factors complicate the matter of uniquely identifying the same image stored in 2 different locations/documents.

Going on the same lines on which fingerprint recognition works, Is there any programmatic process we can follow in order to uniquely identify an image? Irrespective of the format its stored on disk or image dimensions.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to use QRCode? Several reasons it would be beneficial: You don't have to write a library for it because there are good ones already, built-in error correction (potentially useful for screenshots/scans/whatever), robust transformation invariance since part of the image is used to find orientation, and it can certainly hold enough data to determine uniqueness such as a hash output of your choice.

Comment: @lucidMonkey Thanks for the thought! I dont understand how a QR code can be used.

Comment: @lucidMonkey Thanks for the thought! Could you please explain how we can use QR code in the application of image recognition. QR code, i understand, can store a long string of bytes. However it cannot store as big a data like am image. Please clarify your idea.

Comment: If the image itself can be anything that can be guaranteed unique, my suggestion is to use a something like sha256 hash as the unique data embedded in the QRCode. The QRCode itself is the unique image, not a container for the unique image. sha256 will give you 2^256 possible unique images, which should be much much more than you would ever need. Also, you don't have to worry about image recognition because the images are well formed. Also, even good fingerprint recognition algorithms have some false acceptance and false rejection rate, so qrcode is more robust for your purposes I think.